# How to write sql query expression in formula field of crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2012. Can I use a SQL query expression in formula field in Crystal Reports? If yes then how can I write query formula field?

I want query like this:

```
select age from tblcustomer where id = {datacolumn.name}
```

I want return age of every field is there any way to do this in formula field editor?

Comment: You can't use a formula for that, but you can use a [SQL Expression](http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/07/crystal-reports-using-sql-expression-fields/).

Comment: where is sqlexpression field in field explorer of crystal report.Can you explain a little bit

Comment: in my crystal report formula field,parameter field,special field etc.. but not sql expression field is available in field explorer

Comment: I am using dataset.xsd in my report

Comment: I created a dataTable in dataset.xsd and added in my report but unable to see the sql expression field